# Javascript keyframe composite on animate() method not stacking

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am using a keyframes array and a timing object, in a javascript **animate()** method, to translate() a  tag and to mix the backgroundColor.

```
space.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  let keyframes=[        
    {
      transform: "translate(100px, 20px) ",
      backgroundColor: "red",
    }
  ]

  let keyframes1=[
    {backgroundColor: "green"}
  ]

  let timing1={
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
    fill: "forwards",
    composite: "accumulate",
    //iterationComposite: "accumulate",
  }

  mov.animate(keyframes, timing1)
  cube.animate(keyframes1, timing1)
}
```

but the composite property only works once and then it returns the DOM element to its position.
Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/minimister/gf89aLnp/1/).

How do I accumulate X/Y positions and mix colors on animate()? How can I do the same in ReactJs?